# Chrome Developer Options not getting XHR network requests

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, web-scraping, python-requests

hello i am doing web scraping using python on a site, problem i am facing is that the website is not showing the api calls that it is making to fetch data in the network tab, sharing site link below, script needs to go to the site and get the slots that are reserved/gereseerved and uncheck all other, if somehow could get the api call that the site is using that would be helpful

Link : https://ikbouwmijnhuisin.almere.nl/meer-weten/nieuws/kavelkaart/

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened the network tab first before refreshing or clicking on some of the options on the page? If done right, you should be able to see the XHR calls (Example below)
[image]